# AngularJS accessing values in a complex weather JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am in a process of learning angularJS and I am stuck with accessing the values from the objects I want, in JSON file. Now, I searched the internet for answers, but all I got are really simple examples which I cannot apply in this case.

Here are the screenshots of my tries. The only one that worked out is when I accessed an array of objects, but when I wanted to access values from an object that is not in an array, I could not manage to do it properly.

I want to access and display only values from the object "main":

```
{"temp":293.01,"pressure":1019,"humidity":60,"temp_min":290.15,"temp_max":296.15}
```

Here's the JSON file:

```
{
  "id": 2643743,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200,
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
  },
  "weather": [{
    "id": 800,
    "main": "Clear",
    "description": "Sky is Clear",
    "icon": "01n"
  }],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 293.01,
    "pressure": 1019,
    "humidity": 60,
    "temp_min": 290.15,
    "temp_max": 296.15
  },
  // etc...
}
```

The following three examples didn't work:

```
<div>
    <h1 align="center">Customer List</h1>
    <div class="forecast">
        <div ng-repeat="x in fiveDay">
            <div class="first">
                <p>{{ x.main.temp }}</p>
                <p>{{ x.main.pressure }}</p>
                <p>{{ x.main.humidity }}</p>
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div>
    <h1 align="center">Customer List</h1>
    <div class="forecast">
        <div ng-repeat="x in fiveDay.main">
            <div class="first">
                <p>{{ x.temp }}</p>
                <p>{{ x.pressure }}</p>
                <p>{{ x.humidity }}</p>
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div>
    <h1 align="center">Customer List</h1>
    <div class="forecast">
        <div ng-repeat="x in fiveDay">
            <div class="first">
                <p>{{ x.temp }}</p>
                <p>{{ x.pressure }}</p>
                <p>{{ x.humidity }}</p>
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The last one displayed the wanted info in a div, but it rendered 10 empty divs as well, so I guess that counts as a fail as well.

I would highly appreciate some assistance.

Edit:

This is my JavaScript file:

```
    // create the module and name it scotchApp
        // also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
    var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

    // configure our routes
    scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });
    });



    scotchApp.factory('forecast', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);



    // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
    scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        // create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
    });


    scotchApp.controller('aboutController', ['$scope', 'forecast', function($scope, forecast) {
  forecast.success(function(data) {
    $scope.fiveDay = data;
  });
}]);



    scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
    });
```

I uploaded the app on the web for the sake of exercise:
http://www.freegamesarmy.com/horoskop/index.html#/about

Comment: Please add the javascript code you are using (and ideally create an example in Plunker). It's not clear from your question where fiveDay is coming from or how you are linking it together.

Comment: I don't see 'fiveDay' anywhere in the json.  Please add this to your page just before your ng-repeat and paste what is displayed: `<pre>{{fiveDay | json}}</pre>`

Comment: Could you to make a jsbin or jsfiddle with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `ngRepeat` in your case as the API (http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk) responds with just an object (for current weather I guess). So in your case:

```
<div>
    <h1 align="center">Customer List</h1>
    <div class="forecast">
        <div>
            <div class="first">
                <p>{{ fiveDay.main.temp }}</p>
                <p>{{ fiveDay.main.pressure }}</p>
                <p>{{ fiveDay.main.humidity }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `fiveDay` truly an array of those ('those' being the JSON message that you included) or is it just one of those. If the latter then you shouldn't be using an ng-repeat. I'm assuming the former though.
I put your JSON message into a formatter online ([this one](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)) so you can make sense of it. Here it is...

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -0.13,
        "lat": 51.51
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "Sky is Clear",
            "icon": "01n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 293.01,
        "pressure": 1019,
        "humidity": 60,
        "temp_min": 290.15,
        "temp_max": 296.15
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 4.6,
        "deg": 80
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "dt": 1438976764,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 5091,
        "message": 0.0124,
        "country": "GB",
        "sunrise": 1438922043,
        "sunset": 1438976240
    },
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "cod": 200
}
```

You can see that your first attempt *should* be the correct one.
One thing you can try is to intercept it in the controller and pick one of the fiveDay values out of the array (using `fiveDay[0]`) see if it works there in code. If you're using an IDE with debugging, then break and see what you get.